# LinkedIn Autofill button not showing

Tags: linkedin-api

I want to implement the LinkedIn Autofill into my staging website to test the autofill feature into the website form.

I have created LinkedIn Insight tag and implement into my staging website and follow the instruction guide https://www.linkedin.com/help/lms/answer/a424393/linkedin-autofill-setup-guide?lang=en, the autofill button didn't show out.

In the LinkedIn Campaign Manager, Website Tracking page did show the Tag Domain implement successful with my staging domain listed there.

On my staging site, I use chrome inspection tools and the console show the following error message without any further details
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()

Any suggestion how to implement it?

#linkedin

Answer (score 0):

**Please try it in your production instead of staging.**

We faced a similar error in our staging site where the Linked in Autofill button didn't show up and a 400 error code for https://www.linkedin.com/autofill/ in the console. The reason was the issues with whitelisting. Though the linked in representative confirmed that our staging site has been whitelisted, it still didn't work. They suggested us to take it to production and check. It was actually working in Production as expected. Please try it in your production instead of staging.

Adding the steps that we followed:

1. Add linked in Insight Tag to your website. Please follow the steps [here](https://www.linkedin.com/help/lms/answer/a415868)
2. Add the autofill script to the html page where you want the button to be displayed. Note: If you are using a CMS, where this autofill plugin is being added to modules and re-used across your websites, make sure the script is added inside a proper html structure.
   [Html code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSsX5.png)
3. Check if the Insight tag is working properly by opening the network tab and check for the insight tag link. Please refer the [link](https://www.linkedin.com/help/lms/answer/a425696?trk=hc-articlePage-peopleAlsoViewed)
4. Whitelist your website domains by contacting the Linked In rep.
5. If you get a 400 error for https://www.linkedin.com/autofill/ in your staging site, try it in your production url after it has been whitelisted.